# Django as_p() method equivalent for non-form / display only use cases

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a handful of models with 10+ fields each.  During my first draft of development I am less concerned about how things look and am trying to get to the critical components of the code ASAP.  I love the myForm.as_p method built into the Forms object.  The main benefit is that I can alter the models as needed, make my migrations, and the as_p will show these new fields without me having to change the template.

My questions is: is there an equivalent method for display only use cases?

I have tried combing through the docs but have not found a thing outside of forms.  The ideal would be something like a class based DetailView that in the template can use {{ object.as_p }}.  Anyone know of a dynamic display function like that outside of forms?

As mentioned in the comments, I’m looking for a template tag that renders html for a model instance.

Comment: Are you asking for a model method or template tag that renders some formatted HTML for a model instance?

Comment: @IainShelvington template tag that renders some pre-determined HTML for a model instance.  Exactly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: I created an "as_div" method in the model class for the model I want to display and looped over all the fields with a two column set of  tags.  Here's the method:

```
models.py
...
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
...

class myModel(Model):
  ...

  def as_div(self):
      # build the HTML representation of the model instance
      html = "<div class='modelInstance'>"
      for field in self._meta.fields:
          html += "<div style='display: flex; width: 30%'>"
          html += "<div style='flex: 1'>" + field.verbose_name + "</div>"
          html += "<div style='flex: 1'>" + str(getattr(self, field.name)) + "</div>"
          html += "</div>"
          html += "</div><hr />"
      return mark_safe(html)
```

I then used this method name (as_div) in the HTML template like so:
myModel.html

```
myModels.py
...
{% for myModel in myModels %}
    {{ myModel.as_div }}
{% endfor %}
```

I came upon [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/) while researching the "as_div" helper tag used in the django.forms API.  Per the documentation:

> The template used by as_div(). Default: 'django/forms/div.html'

Which got me thinking, can I just build a template in the django/models/ folder and refer to it like they do for the forms?  Well, turns out, it's even easier.  When you want to manipulate the model at the row level (instances) you just add a method to the model Class.  So I wrote the method above and a bunch of  tags were shown on the webpage.  Whoops.  Turns out you have to mark it as safe using the django.utils.safestring library.  Then it will render as actual HTML.

The drawback now is every model has to have the exact same method added to it's Class.  I don't like repeating code, but this will have to do until I find a cleaner way.